# Does the 'difference' operation add expressiveness to a query language that already includes 'join'?

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra, finite-model-theory

The set difference operator (e.g., `EXCEPT` in some SQL variants) is one of the many fundamental operators of relational algebra. However, there are some databases that do not support the set difference operator directly, but which support `LEFT JOIN` (a kind of outer join), and in practice this can be used instead of a set difference operation to achieve the same effect.

Does this mean that the expressive power of a query language is the same even without the set difference operator, so long as the `LEFT JOIN` operator is maintained? How would one prove this fact?

Comment: To show that they have the same expressive power is showing that the difference operation can be constructed with the left join operation (and possibly other operations in RA).

Comment: SQL <> relational algebra. Which? If relational algebra, which?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In relational algebra, we shall first provide an informal definition of left (outer) join, and proceed to prove that it, renaming, selection, join and projection can construct difference, as well as that difference, selection and union can be used to construct left (outer) join. Actually, we'll end up doing it in the reverse order: we'll show how to construct left joins using differences, and then we'll show how to construct differences using left joins.

Let $R$ and $S$ have schemata $(R', T)$ and $(T, S')$, respectively, where $R'$ and $S'$ are the sets of attributes in one schema but not the other, and $T$ is the set of common attributes.

Let $w = (\epsilon, \epsilon, ..., \epsilon)$ be the null tuple for schema $S'$. That is, it is the tuple consisting of all null values for each attribute of $S'$. Then, we define left outer join as follows: `R LEFT JOIN S` is the set of all tuples $(r, t, s)$ belonging to schema $(R', T, S')$ where...

1. $(r, t)$  is a tuple in $R$;
2. (a) $(t, s)$ is a tuple of $S$ or (b) $s = w$;
3. If $(r, t, s)$ is in the set for $s \neq w$, then $(r, t, w)$ is not in the set.

Example: $R$'s schema is $(A_{1}, A_{2}, A_{3})$, $S$'s schema is $(A_{2}, A_{3}, A_{4})$, and we have that $R = \{(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)\}$ and $S = \{(2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 6)\}$. By (1) and (2) we get the intermediate result $\{(1, 2, 3, 4),(1, 2, 3, 6), (1, 2, 3, \epsilon),(4, 5, 6, \epsilon)\}$. By (3) we must remove $(1, 2, 3, \epsilon)$, since we have (for instance) $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $s = 4 \neq \epsilon = w$. We are thus left with $\{(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 6), (4, 5, 6, \epsilon)\}$, the expected result for a left join.

Theorem: `R LEFT JOIN S` is equivalent to `(R EQUIJOIN S) UNION ((((PROJECT_T R) DIFFERENCE (PROJECT_T S)) EQUIJOIN R) JOIN w)`.

Proof: `(R EQUIJOIN S)` gives us everything required by (1) and (2a). We claim that `((((PROJECT_T R) DIFFERENCE (PROJECT_T S)) EQUIJOIN R) JOIN w)` gives us everything of the form `(r, t, w)` required by (2b) and (3).

To see this, first notice that `(((PROJECT_T R) DIFFERENCE (PROJECT_T S)) EQUIJOIN R)` is the set of all tuples in $R$ for which there is no corresponding tuple in $S$. To see that, it suffices to note that by projecting the common attributes out of $R$ and $S$ (the attribute set $T$) and taking the difference, one is left with all and only those tuples (with schema $T$) which are represented in $R$ but not $S$. By the `EQUIJOIN` with $R$, we recover all and only those tuples in $R$ which have values for attributes in $T$ which are present in $R$ but not in $S$; namely, precisely the set of tuples we have so far claimed.

Next, notice that the schema of `(((PROJECT_T R) DIFFERENCE (PROJECT_T S))` is the same as that of $R$ (namely, $(R', T)$), while the schema of $w$ is $S'$. The `JOIN` operation is therefore a Cartesian product, we we get all tuples of the form $(r, t, w)$ where there is no $(t, s)$ in $S$ corresponding to $(r, t)$ in $R$.

To see that this is precisely the set of tuples we needed to add to `R EQUIJOIN S` in order to construct `R LEFT JOIN S`, consider the following: by construction, (3) is satisfied, since `R EQUIJOIN S` cannot contain $(r, t, s)$ if `((((PROJECT_T R) DIFFERENCE (PROJECT_T S)) EQUIJOIN R) JOIN w)` contains $(r, t, w)$ (if it did, then the second part's containing $(r, t, w)$ would be a contradiction); if we were to add another $(r, t, w)$ not in `((((PROJECT_T R) DIFFERENCE (PROJECT_T S)) EQUIJOIN R) JOIN w)`, then there would be a $(t, s)$ in $S$ corresponding to $(r, t)$ in $R$, and by the definition of `EQUIJOIN`, $(r, t, s)$ would also be in `R LEFT JOIN S`, a contradiction of (3). This completes the proof.

Now we show that left join can be used to construct difference:

Theorem: `R DIFFERENCE S` is equivalent to `PROJECT_T(SELECT_{t'=w}(R LEFT JOIN (SELECT_{s=s'}(((S JOIN RENAME_{T->T'}(S)))))))`

Proof: Notice that here, $R'$ and $S'$ are empty, since all attributes are shared for `DIFFERENCE` to make sense. First, we create a new relation from $S$ by duplicating the attribute set in $S$ (handled by `RENAME` and `JOIN`) so that it consists of tuples $(t, t')$ on attribute set $(T, T')$ where $t = t'$ (handled by the `SELECT`). The left join leaves us with tuples of the form $(t, t')$ where $t=t'$ or $t'=w$. Now, to get rid of entries which do also appear in $S$, we must keep only the tuples of the form $(t, w)$, which is handled by the outermost `SELECT`. The last `PROJECT` gets rid of the temporary attribute set $T'$ and leaves us with the difference in terms of the original schema.

Example: Let $R = \{(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)\}$ and $S = \{(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)\}$. We first get $S$ with the `RENAME`d attribute set $T'$: $\{(3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)\}$. The `JOIN` operation gives us the Cartesian product with all nine possible pairings; this set is not written here for reasons of formatting. The `SELECT` then pares this down to $\{(3, 4, 3, 4), (5, 6, 5, 6), (7, 8, 7, 8)\}$. The `LEFT JOIN` with $R$ gives $\{(1, 2, \epsilon, \epsilon), (3, 4, 3, 4), (5, 6, 5, 6)\}$. The `SELECT` gives $\{(1, 2, \epsilon, \epsilon)\}$. The `PROJECT` gives $\{(1, 2)\}$, the desired answer.

Comment: Please edit your post to use LaTeX syntax. Start by enclosing all your formula in \$ symbols (for example, \$(1,2)\$ becomes $(1,2)$). Keywords like select should be put in \` (for instance, \`SELECT\` becomes `SELECT`).

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for pointing out that I should be using LaTeX for this. I have made a good-faith attempt at LaTeX'ing the math and backtick'ing the code... please let me know if there's anything else I should do. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, thanks! You might want to consider \$\$...\$\$ to created indented (not inline) pieces of math. This can often improve readability if used correctly. MathJax also supports numbered equations but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I think your logic is faulty here. You are using `DIFFERENCE` to define `LEFT JOIN`, and then you use `LEFT JOIN` to express `DIFFERENCE`, concluding that SQL can do without it. For this to be valid, you should express `LEFT JOIN` in terms of operators **other than `DIFFERENCE`**, and then prove that `DIFFERENCE` is equivalent to it.

Comment: @Janoma I don't think that's required... we're trying to show that difference can be expressed in terms of left joins, so a functioning left join is assumed. Think about it: if what you're saying had merit, I could claim that LEFT JOIN is the "fundamental" or "necessary" operation, and demand that you define DIFFERENCE in terms of the other operators, but not LEFT JOIN. I have shown that each can simulate the other, so neither is more or less "fundamental" than the other... what makes DIFFERENCE special? In prop. logic, NOT and AND are complete, as are OR and NOT; you don't need all three.

Comment: My point is that you used set-theoretical difference **to define** `LEFT JOIN` (the third condition). Thus, if a RDBMS supports a `LEFT JOIN` operator as defined, then **it already knows** how to do a `DIFFERENCE`, even if it doesn't offer this operator to users by means of a reserved keyword. If you eliminate this `DIFFERENCE` from the RDBMS, the system will no longer know how to compute a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Janoma I'm almost sure I understand your point; that said, I'm almost sure that it's not a valid one. First off, there's a difference between the `DIFFERENCE` operator in the relational algebra and the set-theoretic idea of set difference. Secondly, the fact that my definition of `LEFT JOIN` uses the set-theoretic notion of set difference is incidental (in a sense; the fact that you can define it like that is actually a pretty big part of the reason one can simulate the other). Third, you still haven't pointed out how your arguments don't apply the other way around.

Comment: @Janoma Another way of looking at this is the following: what I am showing is that you can't have `PROJECT`, `EQUIJOIN`, `UNION` and `DIFFERENCE` without also being able to do `LEFT JOIN` even if you can't use `LEFT JOIN` in a query, and you can't have `PROJECT`, `SELECT`, `LEFT JOIN`, `JOIN` and `RENAME` without also being able to do `DIFFERENCE`, even if you weren't allowed to use `DIFFERENCE` in a query. So, if somebody had a way of computing left joins without doing a difference (even an oracle), the system could _still_ do `DIFFERENCE`. That's what we're showing here.

Comment: @Janoma The point is to show that `DIFFERENCE` operator doesn't add any expressive power: that for every query that uses it, there exists a query that doesn't use it and that has the exact same effect on every input. This is shown by Patrick87's second theorem, if you'll accept that. Your intuition that `LEFT JOIN` can be said to really performs a difference is supported by his first theorem.

Comment: @Patrick87 Your proof relies on NULL values. There are two problems with that: 1) They are not assumed in the relational model, so you should really introduce them first. 2) What if they occur in the input relations?

Comment: @reinierpost Maybe I'm just misunderstanding your point, but I do introduce $w$, the null tuple, for a relation... in general, the definition of left outer join requires the existence of null values (since these can appear in the result of a left outer join), although I agree that difference (etc.) does not require these. Maybe more generally, can you explain what difficulty would arise by simply assuming the domain of every attribute to be augmented by a single special element, $\epsilon$, otherwise not belonging to any attribute domain?

Comment: @Patrick87: I mean, you introduce the assumption that null tuples *exist* - the problem I see is that what you need is *fresh* tuples, guaranteed not to occur in the input, and a second reason it is relevant is that it appears to be crucial to the ability to simulate difference, so it might be rejected as a proof by purely relational means for that reason.

Comment: @reinierpost Sorry, I think I must still not quite understand. Do you have a counterexample in mind? Please feel free to edit the answer to include it if you do... perhaps I could see where some difficulty might arise if input relations contain instances of the null tuple, but it seems like definitions of all relational operators could be adjusted to deal with this (potentially) exceptional scenario.

Comment: Your 2 operator implementations use other than the parameters & primitive operators--you rely on further operators that construct relations & extract parts of relations & you construct expressions per parts. (You don't define your relations or operators or "is equivalent to".) You don't show that your implementations work when input can have nulls--your DIFFERENCE implementation assumes a w is from the LEFT JOIN but it could have been input. EQUIJOIN does not drop compared attributes. PS "schema" has multiple uses but you don't define yours & you use idiosyncratic set notation.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN as implemented by SQL, does not produce relations as its result (because some attributes of the result will not have a value).

Ergo, LEFT JOIN as implemented by SQL, is not a direct counterpart of any relational algebra operator.

Ergo, The **relational** difference operator cannot be expressed in terms of LEFT JOIN (because LEFT JOIN cannot possibly be part of the relational algebra, this being because LEFT JOIN produces something that is not a relation, thus violating closure of the algebra).

Any set of primitive operators of a **relational** algebra **that satisfies closure** that I know of, always includes either relational difference or else relational semidifference.